# How to call top-level make with same arguments?

Tags: makefile

I want always call top-level makefile with same command line. I tried:

```
.PHONY: %
%:
    $(MAKE) -C ${CURDIR}/.. ${CURDIR}/$*
```

but its does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Are you saying that for any invocation of make in this directory you want to run make in a different directory, with the same arguments?

You can't *quite* do this, but this will get you close:

```
.DEFAULT:
        $(MAKE) -C ${CURDIR}/.. $@
```

I don't know why you were prefixing the `$*` with `$(CURDIR)` in the target name...?

The big difference between this and the original invocation is that it will run a separate make process for each target; that is if you run `make foo bar` it will invoke the "top-level makefile" twice: once with a target of `foo` and then again with a target of `bar`.  There's no way to avoid this, that I can think of.

Comment: THANKS, don't worry about that prefix - it's artifact

Comment: I took out .NOTPARALLEL.  Thinking about it more, I don't think you need it.